# IDEA не импортирует java.util.List

Tags: java, intellij-idea, list

Столкнулся с проблемой, что `IDEA` не хочет импортировать `java.util.List`. Точнее, мне приходится прописывать импорт вручную, так как `IDEA` не выводит в предлагаемый список эту библиотеку. Как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Upd**

Разобрался, класс был заигнорен в Editor-General-Auto Import

Comment: `SDK` настроен? Посмотрите лог сообщений

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi все настроено, все работает, за исключением этого импорта.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри тут - может у тебя там исключение прописано->File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from Import and Completion.

Comment: Да, в апдейте это уже написал